# ReactJs how do i delete a row from a table?

Tags: reactjs

I am using reactsjs. I have a table that adds rows based on a button click. The rows are also added to an array of rows. When that row is added it has a button in it that will delete that row when clicked. This is what I need to get working. The rows are stored in an array as in an array. I have made an attempt as by looking at examples. With my attempt, the incorrect row is being deleted.

Here is my code that I tried:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      tasks: []
    }
    this.handleDeleteRow = this.handleDeleteRow.bind(this);
  }

handleDeleteRow(i) {
    let rows = [...this.state.rows]
    rows.splice(i, 1)
    this.setState({ 
      rows: rows
    })
  }
```

A snippet of code:

```
<tbody>
{rows.map((row,i) => {
                return(
                    <tr key={i}>
                        <td scope="row" >{i}</td>
                        <td>{row.ex}</td>
                        <td>{row.ex}</td>
                        <td>{row.ex}</td>
                        <td>{row.ex}</td>
                        <td>{row.ex}</td>
                        <td>
                            this is the delete button
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                );
            })}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Use filter... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Can you post snippet how do you render them exactly?

Comment: @ŁukaszWojciechowski I updated the question with a snippet

Comment: @BeauBridges where you calling ` handleDeleteRow ` function?

Comment: What is your delete button code? How are you passing the value of `i` to the handleDeleteRow function?

Comment: What do you mean "the wrong row"? Can you show proof of this? (e.g. where is your actual delete handler being called, and what are you giving it as arguments?)

Comment: @NishantDixit i have an "a" tag that has is coded as a button. <a onClick={this.props.handleDeleteRow.bind(this)} > delete row </a>

Comment: You already binded this to handleDeleteTask in constructor, you do'nt need to bind again and your a tag should be like this `<a onClick={()=>this.props.handleDeleteTask(i)} > delete row </a>`\

Comment: You have to pass the value of i  in `handleDeleteTask` when you click on a tag

Comment: @NishantDixit can you make this an answer it worked

Comment: @wlh did that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on how you are calling `handleDeleteRow`.

From your comment you mentioned this as your call:

```
<a onClick={this.props.handleDeleteTask.bind(this)} > delete row </a>
```

Try this instead:

```
<a onClick={i => this.handleDeleteRow(i)}>Delete Row</a>
```

But you have to make sure you are using the same variable names throughout. In your original code snippet you define `state.tasks`, then in your delete function you set `state.rows`, and in your render function you alternately call `map` on `rows` (for which I can only assume you are destructuring this variable from state like `{rows} = this.state` but then your call a function you haven't defined (at least to us) called `handleDeleteTask`.

You have to be meticulously consistent throughout if you want to see this work.

Answer (score -3):

I believe that the problem is with the key. When you have an array `[a, b, c]` and you remove `a` then in the new array `[b, c]` the keys correspond to the wrong items. Please find better keys for your table.

Comment: How do you suggest I do so?

Comment: It depends on your data structure. Do you have anything that uniquely identifies the row? An id, name or anything else? If not then maybe you could generate something on the fly when constructing/receiving the table data.