# How to Properly delete User on button click using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

This application displays three users from an array. Now am trying to delete each user via its click button.

To this effect, I have referenced a solution found here at stackoverflow
[Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51524118/reactjs-how-do-i-delete-a-row-from-a-table)

**Here is my issue:**

when I click on User 1 to delete it, it will delete user2 instead of user1, If its only user1 that is remaining. if I click on its button,
it will not be deleted at all.

Here is the code

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: [
        { id: "1", name: "user 1" },
        { id: "2", name: "user 2"},
        { id: "3", name: "user 3"}
      ]
    });

 this.handleDeleteRow = this.handleDeleteRow.bind(this);
  }



handleDeleteRow = (pid) => {
alert(pid);
    let data = [...this.state.data];
    data.splice(pid, 1);
    this.setState({ 
      data: data
    })
  }




  render() {


    return (
      <span>
        <label>
          <ul>
            {this.state.data.map(person => (
              <li key={person.id}>
                {person.name}
                <br />

<button onClick={() => this.handleDeleteRow(person.id)} style={{color:'red'}}>Delete</button>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </label>
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In the map function, you give `person.id` as parameter to the handleDeleteRow(). Your id's starts at 1, i guess you trying to delete the wrong array index! If you press the button for person 1, your give id: 1. But delete the second item in the array!

Comment: looks like you have it mostly working. Why not just mess with the logic of deleterow instead of relying on splice alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using your `pid` as an index (in `data.splice(pid, 1)`) but it's actually an id. So for example, when you're clicking to remove the first item, you're calling `this.handleDeleteRow("1")`, but 1 is the second index of the array, therefore it's the second item that is removed.

Try this :

```
data.splice(data.findIndex(({ id }) => id === pid), 1);
```

Comment: Sir Strebler Thanks for the contribution. When I added your solution and click to delete user 1, it will delete both user 1 and user 2 at the same time. Any idea of what is going on..

Comment: What did you change exactly ? The key was to replace `data.splice(pid, 1);` with my line. If that's all you did, then you might have a double click hardware bug with your mouse.

Comment: You are right. the delete button was close to each other and  were inside span element

Comment: Thanks Sir Strebler